# XSLT time zone conversion

Tags: regex, datetime, xslt

I'm working with a system that will only output the server time in Central Time Zone (CT). I need to convert this in XSLT to US Eastern Time.

Is there a built in method to translate this or do I need to use Regex?

```
<node time="02:14 pm CT" />
```

Current Output: **02:14 pm CT**

Desired Output: **03:14 pm ET**

Comment: Does "CT" mean [Central Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone_%28North_America%29)? If so, you only need to add one hour to the given time in order to convert it to Eastern  Time Zone (assuming your regions of interest observe the same DST rules). Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Yes, Central Time Zone. XSLT 1.0

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML input?

Comment: My bad, it was in my original ask but I forgot to indent!

Comment: Can you show both example input and desired output? How do you want to handle times that would cross midnight and be in another day?

Comment: Updated ask with examples. For midnight, it should follow the same logic. Time + 1, so , 12:00 am CT would become 01:00 am ET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two main paths to choose between, converting it into a time and using a time based library, or taking it as a string and doing straight string manipulation. The following is string manipulation:

```
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="'11:14 pm CT'"/> <!-- the input value -->
    <xsl:variable name="hours" select="number(substring-before($time,':'))"/>  <!-- numeric hours -->
    <xsl:variable name="mer" select="substring($time,7,2)"/>  <!-- the am or pm part -->

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$hours &lt; 12">  <!-- if we are 01-11 -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('0', $hours + 1), string-length(concat('0', $hours + 1)) - 1, 2)"/> <!-- add an hour and repad the string with leading zero, messy -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>01</xsl:text> <!-- we were 12, so just use 01 -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($time, 3,4)"/> <!-- pull the minutes forward -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($hours = 11)">  <!-- if we were not 11 for hours we keep the same am/pm -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$mer"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$mer = 'pm'"> <!-- otherwise we flip it -->
                    <xsl:text>am</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>pm</xsl:text>                       
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text> ET</xsl:text>
```

Comment: +1 Works. Would be better if it were converted to a reusable function/call-template. That would allow it to be more easily used inline with text. "Your request was received on [call-template] and will be processed."

Comment: Wrapping this in a named template would be possible. At that point it would probably be worth modifying the logic so that it could handle variable offsets rather than just the fixed one hour offset to ET.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method for this in XSLT 1.0. Regardless, it would have been fairly trivial to do - except for the fact that your time input is in 12-hour format. This makes the process rather tedious, so I have split it off to a processing template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <node>
        <xsl:attribute name="time">
            <xsl:call-template name="time-offset">
                <xsl:with-param name="time" select="node/@time"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </node>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template name="time-offset">
    <xsl:param name="time"/>
    <xsl:param name="offset" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="h12" select="substring($time, 1, 2)"/>
    <xsl:param name="pm" select="contains($time,'p') or contains($time,'P')"/>
    <xsl:param name="h24" select="$h12 mod 12 + 12*$pm"/>
    <xsl:param name="newH24" select="($h24 + $offset + 24) mod 24"/>
    <xsl:param name="newH12" select="($newH24 + 11) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:param name="am.pm" select="substring('AMPM', 1 + 2*($newH24 > 11), 2)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($newH12, '00'), substring($time, 3, 4), $am.pm, ' ET')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above stylesheet is applied to the example input:

```
<node time="12:14 am CT" />
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node time="01:14 AM ET"/>
```